# shell script + match word without echo command

Tags: ksh

the following test syntax is part of ksh script

```
   [[ $PARAM = TRUE ]] &&  [[ ` echo $LINE_FROM_FILE | grep -c Validation ` -eq 1 ]] && print "find Validation word"
```

Can I get some other creative syntax/solution/command to verify if Validation word exists in LINE_FROM_FILE without to use the echo command?

LINE_FROM_FILE="123 Validation V125 tcp IP=1.2.56.4"

lidia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
... && [[ $LINE_FROM_FILE == *Validation* ]] && ...
```

Comment: not good because if I have Validatio and not Validation its also match , did you have other solution

Comment: Are you sure that this is with ksh then? `==` should do glob matching, and `=~` does regex matching.

Comment: try with LINE_FROM_FILE="1 2 3 ValidationWORD" its also match

Comment: But that would match with your original command as well.

Answer (score 0):

if the word separator in the "line from file" is always one or multiple spaces, try this:

```
if [[ " $LINE_FROM_FILE " == *" Validation "* ]]
```

do'nt forget the quotes